# Hovering over item in WordPress list of pages shows Featured Image

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, hover, thumbnails

Client is requesting functionality which would allow WordPress to generate list of child pages, and when an item (text) from that list is hovered, the Featured Image would show. [Here's an example of such functionality.](http://petleyjones.com/artists/)

Upon further research, I found [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/image-hover-over-text). However, upon review it seems as though the Petley Jones website has hardcoded all page links. I could be incorrect. I am needing wp_list_pages or perhaps get_page to be used since there will be many child pages added by staff and not one person.

I am aware of solutions using both JQuery and CSS. JQuery solution seems best for this, however I am not sure how I could go about coupling it with WordPress. CSS would require each item have the same class or ID, which I can implement, but I am not sure how to call unique page IDs within the stylesheet. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to follow the following procedure-

- when you fetch your child pages wrap a div with a class name say `<div class="child_page"></div>` and inside it place your child page's name's php code.
- inside this div below the child page's code add another div with a class say `<div class="child_page_Img"></div>` and inside it place the code too grab the feature image of the specific page.
- add some css in your theme's stylesheet-

`.child_page_Img{display:none;}
.child_page:hover .child_page_Img{display:block;}`

- since ie6 doesn't allow hovering over any element except `a` element, all you can do is to place the `child_page_Img` div in the `a` element of your child pages permalink.

this trick should work.
Thanks

Comment: Please don't forget to tell us whether you succeed or failed with my suggestion.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I wasn't sure if it would work since I have multiple child pages, but it worked. I appreciate your taking the time to respond.

Comment: if it really worked then you may try to accept the answer :) and maybe vote it up...

Comment: My code: `<?php
$pages = get_posts('post_type=page&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&post_parent=5&posts_per_page=-1');
foreach($pages as $post) : ?>
<div class="child_page" id='<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>'>
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  <div class="child_page_Img">            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
</div></div>
<?php
$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&depth=1');
if ($children) { ?>
<ul class='subnav'>
    <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>`